# How to make nails grow faster?

Tags: guitar, health, nailcare

I have injured the nail on my right hand thumb, so I will not be able to use it for some time. I might have to wait until it regrows about 4 mm of length.

Is it possible to make nails grow faster? For example, should I eat some special nutrients, or do any physical procedures?

Comment: Not sure about natural growth, but I know a handful of pretty serious classical guitarists that swear by ping pong balls. Cut them to the proper shape, super-glue to the existing nail, and apparently it's a great substitute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calcium, Gelatin (ie .. jelly) & Vitamin C seem to make my hair & nails grow more.

It will probably depend on your own body though so I have to say this is just what I've found myself, and in no way a definitive answer !

Superglue is a great way to hold your nails steady for a performance- it doesn't last forever but enough for one night, and it may not make your nails 'usable' but it will help hold it together if you catch it on something. the ping-pong ball idea from Charles seems worth a try too.

Bit of info on Gelatin .. 
[Gelatin - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelatin)

Answer (score 2):

Biotin is the answer. Your hair and nails will grow much more quickly and be stronger. If you wanna be really intense about it, I knew someone who would apply this diamond hardener to his nails. Seemed to work well for him.

I think it was something like this: [http://www.amazon.com/Sally-Hansen-Diamond-Strength-Treatment-0-45/dp/B003VDCF2Y/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1410640255&sr=8-1&keywords=diamond+hardner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VDCF2Y)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to make nails grow faster, but I do know of a few ways to strengthen them to prevent it happening again.

Firstly, file your nails, don't let there be any jagged edges which might get caught and break again. It sounds a bit girly, but it really is the only reliable way to keep this from happening.

You can also make them grow stronger with more silica in your diet, there's a lot of information about this online, but mostly it's found in onions and leeks.